# cannot set uid with mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

```
mount -o uid=1000 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

it used to work, i don't know what i am missing.

```
uname -r
3.19.0-21-generic
mount -V
mount from util-linux 2.25.2 (libmount 2.25.0: selinux, assert, debug)
```

help is appreciated. thanks.

edit : filesystem on sdb1 is ext4
edit :

```
journalctl | tail -1
EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
```

edit : when "it used to work" i had vfat on the usb

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the output of *journalctl*?  **Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000"**. You should look up the man, sometimes: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount, it helps, really.

Comment: the man says 'Mount options for adfs', could not figure out what adfs is. though you are right, looking at manual pages really helps, thank for the advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The man page does not list uid or gid options for ext2, 3 and 4 filesystems. On these filesystems the file permissions don't depend on who mounted the filesystem or on mount options, only on the metadata stored within the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

so i was looking for a way to mount a usb device and give an unprivileged user the right to create files and manipulate them, since it is impossible to change uid on a linux partition, the solution here is to use bindfs 
bindfs allow us to mount a directory to another location and alter permission bits

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

here only root can create / modify files in /mnt but after
 
`bindfs -u bob /mnt ~/usb`

bob is able to modify/create files in /mnt through ~/usb , but he is still not able to create/modify files directly in /mnt.

edited upon request of clarification.

Comment: It might be helpful to add some commentary so that readers can learn.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.